# OneTimeWorkRequest does not run when display is off

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I need to do fast periodic background tasks, but PeriodicWorkRequest is limited to 15 mins, so I use OneTimeWorkRequest and set it again on itself.
I set constraints that do not force charging, but according to my test  OneTimeWorkRequest does not run when the display is off and the charging cable is not connected (about after 1 minute stoped)
but when the charging cable is connected it works well!
*I have this issue only on android 12 whether it works on android 6 - 7- 8 and 10 that tested!*

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
                .build();
        WorkRequest sendWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PeriodicSync.class).setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addTag("sendData").setConstraints(constraints).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(Global.Controller().loginActivity).enqueue(sendWorkRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

On android 12, use the `setExpedited()` method in the work request builder:

```
val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<HighPriorityWorker>()       
    .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)   
    .build() 
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
```

Calling `setExpedited()` tells the framework that this work is important and should have priority over other scheduled work.

Comment: Doesn't work! 
Even online mode(display is on and the app is on top) works sometimes not according to time!